# Entity Framework Core SaveChangesAsync does not updating new record to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my controller named `Identities`, I have some actions that update new records to the database, for instance, this is edit action:

```
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EditPost(string? id, string[] selectedCourses)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var currentUser = await _db.AppUsers
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);

            if (currentUser == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (currentUser.UserType == "Student")
            {
                var studentToEdit = await _db.AppUsers
                    .Include(e => e.Enrollments)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.Course)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);

                if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(studentToEdit, "",
                    u => u.UserName, u => u.FirstName, u => u.LastName, u => u.Email,
                     u => u.PhoneNumber, u => u.UserType, u => u.DepartmentID))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // this is for debugging purpose 
                        Console.WriteLine(studentToEdit);
                        // save changes to db
                        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                    catch (DbUpdateException)
                    {
                        // Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.)
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                            "Try again, and if the problem persists, " +
                            "see your system administrator.");
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var lecturerToEdit = await _db.AppUsers
                    .Include(ca => ca.CourseAssignments)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.Course)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);

                if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(lecturerToEdit, "",
                 u => u.UserName, u => u.FirstName, u => u.LastName, u => u.Email,
                 u => u.PhoneNumber, u => u.UserType, u => u.DepartmentID))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(lecturerToEdit);
                        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                    catch (DbUpdateException)
                    {
                        //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.)
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                            "Try again, and if the problem persists, " +
                            "see your system administrator.");
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
            }

            return View(currentUser);
        }
```

And this is the View:

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" asp-controller="Identities" asp-action="Edit">
        <div class="row px-2 border p-4 text-center">
            <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary=ModelOnly></div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="UserName"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control">
                        <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control">
                        <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control">
                        <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Email"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control">
                        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="PhoneNumber"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="PhoneNumber" class="form-control">
                        <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="UserType"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <input asp-for="UserType" class="form-control">
                        <span asp-validation-for="UserType" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label asp-for="Department" class="control-label">Department</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <select class="form-control" asp-for="DepartmentID" asp-items="ViewBag.DepartmentList">
                            <option value="">-- Select Department --</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-8 offset-4">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Update</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success form-control">Back To List</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

`My problem`: When I tried to update new records and save changes to the database, new records were not updated.

`My trials`: I've debugged and set breakpoints to track the new records that I inserted in every input field is ok or not. Surprisingly everything was ok. In either `Console.Writeline(studentToEdit)` or `Console.Writeline(lecturerToEdit)` includes new record data as I expected. But in the final step when I tried `saveChangesAsync`, that new records were not saved to the database at all.

Comment: Remove the `AsNoTracking()`. You are telling EF Core to not track any changes made to the entity. So nothing will update when saving to the DB.

Comment: Any error messages? Exceptions?

Comment: @Matthiee Thank you for the mention and sorry for the late reply! After removed `AsNoTracking()` in `edit post ` and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

As the definition of `AsNoTracking()` states that it is for `read-only`, but I inserted that in the query of the `Edit post` so that it could not updated new recorded to the database. Remove `AsNoTracking()` and it worked.